# Real-time strategy videogame for iOS involving conquering and robots, with 2D cutscenes

Tags: story-identification, video-games

- It might have two teams of red or blue, but don't rely on that information.
- App for iPhone
- I think it was about at least 3 or more years ago probably more.
- Pretty sure it was out before the iPad, but might not have been
- Was the kind of real time strategy game where you had a hero and could conquer stuff to make more robots, playing against an opponent using either LAN or Wi-Fi or both; I can't remember. Also had a campaign.
- The cutscenes were 2D, not 3D.

Comment: I'd think robots waging war would be sci-fi...

Comment: “”I think it was about at least 3 or more years ago probably more... Pretty sure it was out before the iPad”. The iPad came out seven and a half years ago.

Comment: @Jonas: I don't suppose that, with an answer present, this might have given you more memories of details of what you played? For example, you can sometimes add all of the ways in which an answer is wrong, details you hadn't thought to mention.

Answer (score 9):

Could you be thinking of [Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_(video_game))?

[image: Cover of Z]

> Z (pronounced Zed) is a 1996 real-time strategy computer game by The Bitmap Brothers. It is about two armies of robots (red and blue) battling to conquer different planets.

....

> Unlike traditional real-time strategy (RTS) games, collecting resources or building specific structures is unnecessary for creating an army - the same principle that was introduced by Nether Earth, one of the RTS games ancestors. Regions and structures within their borders that actually manufacture the units are captured by moving troops to their respective flags. All you need to do is to hold acquired position for a certain amount of time while the unit is manufacturing. The more regions are under the player's control, the less the time required. More powerful units take more time to construct.

....

> A mobile version of Z was developed by Peter Harrap and TickTock Games and was published by KavCom. It was released on iPhone and iPad in 2011.

It's [still listed in the iTunes store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/z-the-game/id504560232?mt=12), at $2.99 as of 2017-October-26.

Here's a static screenshot:
[image: Z - game screenshot]

Here's some footage on the iOS:

Found by searching on Google for `ios rts robots "red and blue"`

Comment: no, it had 2d cutscenes thank you for trying though. sory for the response delay i was homeless for a while

Answer (score 4):

I think [*Robocalypse*](https://uk.ign.com/articles/2008/11/07/robocalypse-review) might be what you are looking for.

[image: Robocalypse screenshot]

It was released in 2008 for the Nintendo DS and [on the iPhone in 2009](http://www.robocalypse.com/iPhone/).

> Living up to its name, players are in command of an army of robots defending the Earth against other, evil robots. The catch is, your commanders have been programmed with the minds of aged World War II veterans. Robocalypse' funny, self-referential script comes from Jay Lender (SpongeBob Squarepants) and his writing partner Micah Wright.

The cutscenes are in a 2-d art style:

Answer (score -2):

Command a swarm of robots in Robocide! Reclaim the galaxy as you explore far away planets and battlefields, collect and upgrade heroic Titans, and battle other players in the arena to earn rewards!

FEATURES

- COMMAND over 500 robots with the touch of a finger
- COLLECT and upgrade Titans
- BATTLE other players in the Arena
- DEFEND your base and ambush rival players
- DISCOVER other planets as you journey through the single player campaign
- JOIN friends in Alliances and help each other
- TRACK your progress with the Apple Watch companion app

PLAYER REVIEWS

With an average rating of 4.5 stars, here’s what our players had to say...

“Apple should give us the ability to put a 6 star rating once a year, this game would have my 6 stars."

“Game mechanics are great. Fun and addictive. Good progression and different game modes."

"Love the UI, love the game in general. I'm not a Starcraft person but hey, this one got me ;)"

Edit:sad news it has been deleted

Comment: Was this out 2014 or earlier? Red and blue forces? 2D cutscenes?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Instead of just copying a posting the marketing blurb for the game it would help if you included screenshots and detailed descriptions of how it matches the points listed in the question.

Comment: FWIW, I watched the demo video, and I think it's a stretch to call the inter-level status views "cutscenes."